# Whats the difference between these 2 script If Statements and why 1 of them Wont work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

- **Code 1** *(Don't care about any other value expet this one, with this value we don't want to continue)*

  ```
    If (!optVal == "Select Report")
  ```
- **Code 2** *(Checking for All options of the DropDown another way)*

  ```
    if (optVal == "LPR-Standard Lease Report" || optVal == "Open Acreage Summary Report" || optVal == "Capital Ownership Report") {
  ```

Following this, theres other code that runs all the functionality.

I check the value of `OptVal` before going into the `If Statement` with Chromes built in `Developer Tools`. The Value that comes in is Definatly NOT *Select Report*.

[image]

*You can see here that there not equal , however my next line is not 234, it is the end of my If Statement below.*

> **Code1** it seems like it doesn't matter what `optVal` is and is always considered `(!optVal == "Select Report")`
>
> **Code2** Runs perfect.

**I wonder if in Javascript the `(!Variable)` is not permitted to have an (!Variable`= value`)??**

Comment: one is uppercase, but you are comparing true to "Select Report", which is not the same. try "!="

Comment: its a typo there both the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an order of operations issue, add some paren's:

```
if (!(optVal == "Select Report"))
```

or use

```
if(optVal != "Select Report")
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is of operator precedence. In this case the unary not operator `!` has precedence over the equals `==` operator so it is executed before.

The first if is actually:

```
if (false == "Select Report)
```

Fix like this:

```
if (optVal != "Select Report")
```

Answer (score 4):

The ! operator has higher precedence than the == operator. You need to add parens or use the != operator

Answer (score 2):

Change the operator to !=, I guess this is what you want

```
if (optVal != "Select Report")
```